# How do you grab an element in a JSON tree without an explicit name in Play 2.0?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been working through parsing .json files in a Play 2.0 project and there is one thing I can't figure out. Here is a snippet from the online docs:

```
{
  "users":[
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 31.0,
      "email": "bob@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kiki",
      "age":  25.0,
      "email": null
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to know is, how do I grab one whole user? The problem is that I can't figure out how to reference the grouping of parameters that represents a single user. I've tried something like

```
( json \\ "users" )
```

which just gives all the users as a single element in a list, and I've tried something like

```
( json \ "users" \ (user)(0))
```

but it seems I have to define 'user' and I have no idea what would be appropriate for that.

Better yet, is there a way to grab all the customers in a list? Or even just iterate over the tree and hit upon each user so I can access all the information of a specific user at once?

Comment: What Play version do you use? Do you plan to go to 2.1?

Comment: I'm using 2.0. This question pertains to a 2.0 project I am working on, so I don't plan on moving to 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the JSON contains a list of objects, you can ask for that element to be extracted as one, using `as[List[JsObject]]`.

For example:

```
val str = """{
  "users":[
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 31.0,
      "email": "bob@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kiki",
      "age":  25.0,
      "email": null
    }
  ]
}"""

val json = Json.parse(str)
val users = (json \ "users").as[List[JsObject]]
users.foreach { user =>
  println("user: " + user)
}
```

Generates:

```
user: {"name":"Bob","age":31.0,"email":"bob@gmail.com"}
user: {"name":"Kiki","age":25.0,"email":null}
```

Each of these list elements support the same operators as the original JSON object, so you can extract individual values using `(user \ "name").as[String]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Jerkson JSON (the JSON library used in Play!) supports this way:

```
(json \ "users")(0)
```

If you want to iterate, you can cast it to JArray (and possibly check the type) and call the `elements` method:

```
(json \ "users").asInstanceOf[JArray].elements foreach {
    ...
}
```

There is probably no better way: https://github.com/codahale/jerkson/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/codahale/jerkson/AST.scala

Comment: But what if I don't know the number of users? Is there a good way to iterate through them all without knowing how many there are?